# Transformation of mutual information to probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Given the upper bound for mutual information of random variables $X$ and $Y$, $I(X;Y)\leq L$, what can we say about their joint distribution? 
I mean for example if $L=0$, then we know $p_{XY}(A\cap B)=p_X(A)p_Y(B)$ for $A$ and $B$ measurable sets, can we somehow transform $I(X;Y)\leq L$ into a property of $p_{XY}$. I am particularly thinking about bounding a quantity like 
$$\sup\{|p_{XY}(A\cap B)-p_X(A)p_Y(B)|\}$$
as a function of $L$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inequality called [Pinsker inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality), expressing a relation between total variation and Kullback-Leibler divergence. For two probability distribution $Q$ and $P$ over the probability space $(S,\Omega)$, we have:

> $$
> \displaystyle\sup_{A\in\Omega}\{P(A)-Q(A)\}\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}D(P||Q)}
> $$

We know $I(X;Y)=D\left(P(X,Y)||P(X)P(Y)\right)$. Therefore if $I(X;Y)<L$ then according to Pinsker inequality we have:

> $$
> \displaystyle\sup_{A\in\Omega}\{P(X,Y)-P(X)P(Y)\}\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}L}
> $$

Comment: Thanks Arash, I appreciate it!

Comment: How can we get come converse result? I mean, how can we find a constant $\alpha$ such that $P(X,Y)\leq P(X)P(Y)+\alpha$ yields $I(X;Y)\leq L_{\alpha}$?